# Restore Object after rotate display in Fragment

Tags: java, android

I need restore Object (View Model) and bind to Layout after rotate display.
I save Object to Byte[] in onSaveInstanceState. 
My problem: onCreateView fired before onActivityCreated and this code binding.setViewModel(templateViewModel) binding Null. How there get saved templateViewModel?

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 TemplateFragmentRecyclerViewBinding binding =  TemplateFragmentRecyclerViewBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false); 
binding.setViewModel(templateViewModel); 
binding.executePendingBindings();
return binding.getRoot();
}

    @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
         byte[] data =savedInstanceState.getByteArray(getString(R.string.templateViewModelData));
        //Serialize
     templateViewModel = (TemplateViewModel) Parcel.convertFromBytes(data);

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
      byte[] data = Parcel.convertToBytes(templateViewModel);
      state.putByteArray(getString(R.string.templateViewModelData), data);
     }
```

Utils function:

```
public static byte[] convertToBytes(Object object) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    out.writeObject(object);
    return bos.toByteArray();

}

public static Object convertFromBytes(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
    return in.readObject();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your model restoring code inside the '**OnCreate**' method of the fragment. '**OnCreate**' is called before '**OnCreateView**'. For more informations about the Android fragments' lifecycle, check this link : [Android Fragments' lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: No this not work'd. OnCreate called once. Later called only OnCreateView